# My List(OF Strings) are being saved as system.string (Empty)

Tags: vb.net, string, csv

I'm trying to delete a selected row, then save the rest into a file. However, when I save it, it totally empties the file.

```
    Console.Write("Please eneter the first name of the student you wish to search for: ")
    searchfname = Console.ReadLine
    searchfname = StrConv(searchfname, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
    Console.Write("Please enter the second name of the student you wish to search for: ")
    searchsname = Console.ReadLine
    searchsname = StrConv(searchsname, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
    Dim foundItem() As String = Nothing
    Dim foundline As String = Nothing
    Dim fnsearch As String = String.Join(searchfname, searchsname)
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv"))
    For Each line As String In lines
        If searchfname = item(3) And searchsname = item(4) Then
            Console.WriteLine(line)
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you wish to delete this record? (y/n)")
        End If
        Dim answer As String
        answer = Console.ReadLine
        If answer = "y" Or answer = "Y" Then
            Console.Clear()
            lines.Remove(line)
            Using sw As New StreamWriter("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv")
                sw.WriteLine(lines.ToString)
            End Using
        ElseIf answer = "n" Or answer = "N" Then
            staffmenu()
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You are not writing the file correctly.  Use File.WriteAllLines() instead.

Comment: you got several very good answers here - and on 7 of previous questions.  You should start accepting answers when they help.

Comment: nothing to do with your question but is your search for JoeBlogs or Joe Blogs.... If the latter then change your join so that it includes a space between searchfname and searchsname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line in your code:

```
sw.WriteLine(lines.ToString)
```

Extract the `lines.ToString` expression from that statement. The result of that expression is "`System.String`". You are telling your stream writer to write the text "System.String" to the file.

To fix it, you need something more like this:

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv")
    For Each line As String In lines
        sw.WriteLine(line)
    Next line
End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `List(Of T).ToString` does not produce a value that includes the elements of the collection.  Instead it will just return the type name.

The API you are looking for is `File.WriteAllLines`.  Using this instead of `StreamWriter` and the `Using` block

```
File.WriteAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv", lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that this issue can be resolved from the given answers and comment, but I would like to add an alternative to use [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function in writing to a file. Try like this may be of help:

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(.....)
   sw.WriteLine(Join(lines.ToArray(), Environment.NewLine))
End Using
```

Since using VB.Net, this is a vb.net specific solution can not be used in C#. For C#, use [string.join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Hope it helps too!